# Why a method can ref an undefined variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

I'm new to python, and trying to read bottle.py source code

In the document, we have to

```
from bottle import route, run
```

to use bottle.

I try to read the source code where route is just a function defind in line 2443 by

```
# Shortcuts for common Bottle methods.
# They all refer to the current default application.

def make_default_app_wrapper(name):
    ''' Return a callable that relays calls to the current default app. '''
    @functools.wraps(getattr(Bottle, name))
    def wrapper(*a, **ka):
        return getattr(app(), name)(*a, **ka)
    return wrapper

route = make_default_app_wrapper('route')
```

in the make_default_app_wrapper, app is called, but app is defined in line 3325

```
app = default_app = AppStack()
```

so when the function make_default_app_wrapper is called, there should be no object called app(I guess?), so how does the returned func know what the app is pointing to? Am I getting anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `make_default_app_wrapper` is called, it *defines* `wrapper`, but `wrapper` itself is not called. It is only when `wrapper` (or `route`) is called that `app` needs to be defined.

When `wrapper` is *defined*, Python parses the line

```
return getattr(app(), name)(*a, **ka)
```

and determines that the bare name `app` is not a local variable since it was never on the left-hand side of an assignment or listed as an argument. This only affects the way `app` will be looked-up (when `wrapper` is called), it does not attempt to look up the value of `app` at this time.

When `wrapper` is *called*, and Python executes the statement

```
return getattr(app(), name)(*a, **ka)
```

Python looks up the value for `app` in the global namespace. Note that the value of `app` could even change from one call of `wrapper` to the next. Python would not know about that. The *value* of `app` is not hard-coded. It is looked-up each time `wrapper` is called.

Comment: So the key point is if `app` is defined when `make_default_app_wrapper` is called. If `app` is defined, it is a closure, if not, `wrapper` looks up `app` every time it is called.

Comment: Well, not quite -- even if `app` is defined when `make_default_app_wrapper` is called, `app` will be looked up every time.

Comment: Uhh? Then what if I defined `app` and want to call it no matter there is other `app` defined later or not?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. If `app` is defined in the global namespace when `make_default_app_wrapper` is called, `app` will be looked up every time. If `app` is defined inside `make_default_app_wrapper`, then yes, `make_default_app_wrapper` is a closure, and the value of `app` will be the same every time.

Comment: Oh! I see. I misunderstood closure. I thought it just takes wherever defined previously and keeps the reference.